# Include java files in Ear project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ear

I have all the sources for a project but not the project folder nor the original directory structure so I imported the EAR file into eclipse and it generates all the Web part right, so I can edit this part but it imported other important stuff as class files.  I have all the java files for those class files but I don't know how to include them in the project so I can edit them and build with the changes.

Comment: Should we assume these .class files are used inside the web application?

Comment: Yes.  The class files were imported by eclipse into a ImportedClasses folder inside the Web project

Comment: Generally, .class files go in a Web Application's `/WEB-INF/classes/` folder.  Many build systems (such as Maven or Gradle) will do this for you if you tell it that your web project has a dependency on a code project.

Comment: Ok, I can move them to that folder then? And where do I put the .java files so the class files are compiled again?